# Check if Crystal Reports parameter is from sub report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am looping through a Crystal Reports parameter collection and assigning values to them if they are set in code and displaying a parameter form with the remaining unfilled parameters.

This code is working fine but when a sub report is added that uses linked parameters, they are showing up as well.  This is because the sub report parameters are included in the main report parameter collection.

Is there a *sub report parameter* type to filter them out?